# Sending post by email in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email, blogs

I just set up a site/blog in WordPress, so I'm using the latest version (4.2.2, I think).

I'm trying to use the feature that allows me to post new articles via email.

I went in to settings and set up the Post by Email settings. I THINK I am supposed to set up a new email address, so I did at my webhost (Bluehost) cPanel. In WordPress I entered the mail server that my webhost says I should use, the email address I created, and the password for that email address. For the POP3 port, I wasn't sure if I should use the incoming or outgoing port, so I tried both (see below).

I found [this article](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_post_via_email_feature_in_wordpress/) that says after doing all of the above, you have to go to http:\www.mysite.com\wordpress\wp-mail.php. (If this is a required step, why doesn't the Post via e-mail settings page in WP say so???) Unless it isn't a required step...

But I digress... I changed the url appropriately for my installation and tried to open the wp-mail.php page, but I got this error message for BOTH ports (incoming and outgoing):

POP3 connect: Error []

Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email says that its depreciated and will probably be removed so its best if you download one of their suggested plugins and configure it within the plugin of your choice.